# Prove that if p is an odd prime and p does not divide $ac$, then $ax^2+bx+c \equiv 0$ mod $p$ and $cx^2+bx+a \equiv 0$ mod $p$

Tags: number-theory

Prove that if p is an odd prime and p does not divide $ac$, then $ax^2+bx+c \equiv 0$ mod $p$ and $cx^2+bx+a \equiv 0$ mod $p$ have the same number of solutions.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Let $x$ be a nonzero solution of the first congruence. Then $x^{-1}$ exists and satisfies the second congruence.

Comment: Look up [reciprocal / reverse polynomial,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reciprocal_polynomial#Properties) see esp. property $(1)\ \ $

Answer (score 1):

**HINT** Let $y$ be the inverse of $x$ in $\pmod{p}$. If $ax^2+bx+c \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$, multiplying by $y^2$, we obtain $a+by+cy^2 \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$.